# how to save image from RepositoryItemPictureEdit in DevExpress gridControl to sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, devexpress

I used to use this code the save images from DevExpress PictureEdit to SQL database

```
byte[] Picture;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureEdit.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Picture = ms.ToArray();
```

now I have gridControl whith one column "Image"

```
void CreateImageTable()
    {
        dtimage.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));

        gridControl4.DataSource = dtimage;
    }
```

and I use this code to add images to gridControl

```
        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new XtraOpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.Filter = "Image|*.JPG;*.BMP;*.PNG;*.JPEG;*.GIF";
        ofd.Title = Resources.insertImage;
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        for (int z = 0; z < ofd.FileNames.Length; z++)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileNames[z]);
            DataRow row = dtimage.NewRow();
            row[0] = img;
            dtimage.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

now i create `

```
  RepositoryItemPictureEdit imgdaged = new RepositoryItemPictureEdit();
  gridControl4.RepositoryItems.Add(imgdaged);
        imgdaged.SizeMode = PictureSizeMode.Zoom;
        imgdaged.NullText = " ";
        imgdaged.PictureStoreMode = PictureStoreMode.ByteArray;
        imgdaged.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        gridView4.Columns["Image"].ColumnEdit = imgdaged;
```

but when i try to use this code

```
imgdaged.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

i get this error:CS1061  'RepositoryItemPictureEdit'does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no accessible extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
this is my code to execute a stored procedure

```
public void AddRawMaterialRecommendationImage(int FK_OrderNumber, string UserID, DateTime CreationDate,byte[] RawDamagedimage)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DAL.Open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];

        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@FK_OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = FK_OrderNumber;

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[1].Value = UserID;

        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@CreationDate", SqlDbType.Date);
        param[2].Value = CreationDate;

        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@RawDamagedimage", SqlDbType.Image);
        param[3].Value = RawDamagedimage;

        DAL.ExcuteCommande("AddRawMaterialRecommendationImage", param);
        DAL.Close();

    }
```

i try to use this code but unfortunately did not work for me

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtimage.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = dtimage.Rows[i];
                byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(row["Image"].ToString());
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                damaged.AddRawMaterialRecommendationImage(Convert.ToInt32(txtBon.Text), Program.UserID, DateTime.Now, imageBytes);
            }
```

how I can solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, This the code that worked:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtimage.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = dtimage.Rows[i];
                Image img = (Bitmap)row["Image"];
                byte[] Picture;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Picture = ms.ToArray();
                damaged.AddRawMaterialRecommendationImage(Convert.ToInt32(txtBon.Text), Program.UserID, DateTime.Now, Picture);//row["Image"]

            }
```

I have delete the RepositoryItemPictureEdit .